# Git back merge shows files deleted in sandbox

Tags: git, gerrit

I am working on a feature that has many new files(eg A.class,B.class,C.class) added in sandbox X.

I have merged my sandbox branch X to master and due to some issue, I reverted the merge to master.

Now the files(eg A.class,B.class,C.class) will be deleted in master and the same files will be present in sandbox.

now i am trying to back merge master to sandbox, the files show as delete.

I have around 200 newly added files and lot of changes in existing files too. I know this is how it should work. But i need those files in sandbox and my back merge should not delete the files in sandbox.

My work around is to update newly added files in sandbox X with some changes like space and then will back merge from master so that it shows conflict and will accept sandbox X files while resolving conflict.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you would *not* merge `master` back to `X`.

If you are the only one working on X, you would *rebase* X on top of master: your files would be preserved, would not show as deleted then.

```sh
git switch X
git rebase master
git push --force # OK if you were the only one working on X
```

Comment: There are couple of team working on X and X has new commits also.

Comment: @Vigneshpalanisamy It is alright: new commits will be rebased as well. You just need to communicate with those teams, for them to reset their local branch to origin/X once the rebase and force push have been done (for this one time).